# Plasma shows themes, etc. as installed, though they are not and vice versa

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes, 17.04, plasma

Running Kubuntu 17.04.

When I try to get new desktop themes, etc. there is a mismatch between what system settings show and what get new things dialog shows. The get new things dialog shows several themes as 'installed'. But they are not. I remember installing some of them earlier and removing them later.

How do I remove this mismatch?

Comment: Is this an upgrade ? How did you install and remove themes ? where did you put them ? Can you post a screen shot of the dialog and an example of a missing theme ? Normally themes are stored in /usr/share/apps/plasma/desktoptheme. A theme is described by a .desktop file in /usr/share/apps/desktoptheme. I am guessing remove / delete themes and .desktop theme files you no longer use, but themes can also be in your users home.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Here are answers to all your questions. No. This is not an uppgrade. It was a near-fresh install of Kubuntu 17.04. I installed themes from Settings -> Workspace theme -> Desktop theme -> Get new theme. I removed them from Settings -> Workspace theme -> Desktop theme -> Remove theme. I run both the commands as a normal user so I believe they are stored in my ~ folder somewhere.  I will add another comment for screenshots.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen [Here](http://i.imgur.com/81kjE1L.png) is a screenshot showing themes currently installed on my computer. But when I try to install new themes as in [this](http://i.imgur.com/IwqjZP4.png) screenshot, you can see it is saying K10ne theme is installed whereas it, actually, is not. I had installed and removed it.

Comment: I am not certain, but I think user installed themes are located in ~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme . You may have to search a bit. Try deleting any remaining directories from uninstalled themes and I would also file a bug report.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It is `~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme` in my case.

Comment: OK, is it fixed ? (it is ~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme here, Fedora fanboi)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen No. It is not fixed. I just told you the location of desktop theme files.

Comment: delete the theme files you removed from the graphical KDE theme manager, log out and back in. If that does not fix the issue, file a bug report and manage themes outside that kde tool =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Few words of the KDE Get Hot New Stuff (GHNS)**

This is with the KDE Frameworks 5

Glossary: https://userbase.kde.org/Glossary#Get_Hot_New_Stuff

> Get Hot New Stuff (GHNS) is an open standard that makes it easy for
>   users to download and install various extensions for their
>   applications. Our implementation of GHNS is used by Plasma (for
>   example to get new desktop themes), and by many applications and
>   widgets.

When you are using the System Settings Add-On Installer the bookkeeping (installed, removed, ...) is made to the knsregistry xml file at the $HOME/.local/share/knewstuff3/. Plasma theme registry is at : $HOME/.local/share/knewstuff3/plasma-themes.knsregistry.

[image]

Sample plasma-themes.knsregistry:

[image]

There are also other ways to install and remove the themes, service menus, etc. You could install and remove things by hand, with the distribution package management (apt) or with the KDE tools (kpackagetool5). So the system settings can't only rely the knewstuff registers. The browsers are showing the real situation. What themes are at the right place and have the right format.

Plasma desktop theme browser window(kcmshell5 kcm_desktoptheme):

[image]

The plasma system settings desktop theme module is showing the themes from the /usr/share/plasma/desktoptheme/ and $HOME/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/.

**Few tests**

1) Testing with the 'Adapta KDE' desktop theme

Installation: Installs fine

- marked to the plasma-themes.knsregistry
- unpacked to the $HOME/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/

Removal from the plasma Desktop Theme browser

- removed from the $HOME/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/
- plasma-themes.knsregistry status is still installed !

Removal from the 'System Settings Module Add-On Installer'

- removed from the $HOME/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/
- removed plasma-themes.knsregistry

2) Testing installation with the 'K10ne Next' theme

Executing with the Konsole:

```
$ kcmshell5 desktoptheme
```

Error =>

```
Command failed "kpackagetool5 -t Plasma/Theme -r /tmp/k10next_final.7z"
Command ' "kpackagetool5 -t Plasma/Theme -i /tmp/k10next_final.7z" ' failed with code 4
```

But the plasma-themes.knsregistry has:

```
<status>installed</status>
```

and the 'System Settings Module Add-On Installer' shows:

[image]

Executing

> kpackagetool5 -t Plasma/Theme -i /tmp/k10next_final.7z

More information:

> Error: Installation of /tmp/k10next_final.7z failed: Could not open
>   package file, unsupported archive format: /tmp/k10next_final.7z
>   application/x-7z-compressed

Note !

It is possible to unpack the k10next_final.7z with the Ark to the $HOME/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/ .

**Repairing the GHNS**

The knsregistry files are text files (xml). You could remove the part between the `<stuff>... </stuff>` if there are already removed files.

Comment: That was a great answer and at least explains what is happening. So, when I remove a theme from Get New Stuff dialog, it only affects the knsregistry. Correct? Also, does the same problem exist on other DEs like Gnome?

Comment: Added few examples test what is working and what is not working. I can't say nothing of the Gnome.

Comment: I think it is best that we uninstall it from where we install it. :) That keeps things sane.