# How to copy KDE theme from openSUSE to Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes

Is there a way to copy the theme that openSUSE has in KDE to Kubuntu? Being a long time Gnome user, I am a newbie in KDE. IMHO openSUSE does a better job designing KDE. Little details here and there, i.e. the scroll bar in the terminal is black and descent, whereas the one in Kubuntu is a bit flashy. Though I prefer the Ubuntu way of doing things, which is why I do not want to switch to openSUSE just for design preferences. What I am looking for is a way to export all the design aspects of openSUSE and then import them into Kubuntu. Is that possible without greater difficulties?

**EDIT:**

Kubuntu 18.04 terminal:

- plasmashell: 5.12.4
- Qt: 5.9.5
- KDE Frameworks: 5.44.0
- kf5-config: 1.0

[image]

openSUSE Tumbleweed KDE terminal:

- plasmashell: 5.13.4
- Qt: 5.11.1
- KDE Frameworks: 5.49.0
- kf5-config: 1.0

[image]

Comment: KDE is from upstream of both Kubuntu & OpenSUSE, so at most you like the configuration of opensuse better than kubuntu, as neither design it (though depending on what versions you are comparing, it could be nothing more than you liked one version of KDE better than another one on the other distro). Because the configs you're talking about are KDE (which isn't unique to either) it will transfer from one to the other as long as versions of KDE are similar. Some files are in ~/.config, others in ~/.local (esp. themes) for KDE5.  You can just copy these from machine to machine.

Comment: Please edit your question to show that you're comparing konsole from, it appears, Tumbleweed which is most likely using plasma 5.13+ with konsole from Kubuntu (version not specified) probably with no higher than Plasma 5.12.6. These details could matter.

Comment: @DKBose Added versions to above post.

Comment: So a lot has changed between 5.12 and 5.13. I don't know whether the difference is due to that or whether OpenSuse's theme has always been prettier ;)

Answer (score 2):

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

I haven't tried what you want to do but there are additional themes for you to try from within Kubuntu itself. It may so happen that you like one of them.

Open *System Settings* [image: syssett] in your launcher.

Then, in the *Appearance section*, open *Workspace Theme* to get a *Look and Feel* window:

[image: L&F]

You'll see a *Get New Looks ...* button in the lower right corner. Clicking on that will get you to a window offering you several alternative themes:

[image: Download new L&F]

If you're totally new to things, I'd avoid the ones mentioning "Kvantum" because, from what I understand, they're more complex.

For example, I sorted the available themes by "Most downloaded" and chose the top one, *Arc KDE* by clicking the install button *Install* next to it:

[image: Install Arc KDE]

Then, I went back to *Appearances* and saw that Arc Dark was an option in *Look and Feel*. I selected it and clicked *Apply* in the lower right corner:

[image]

The information for the new theme, is stored locally in `~/.local/share/color-schemes`:

```
dkb@kububb:~/.local/share/color-schemes$ ls
Arc.colors  ArcDark.colors  Breeze1.colors
dkb@kububb:~/.local/share/color-schemes$
```

If you want the light variant, you need to again open *System Settings*, and this time open *Colors*. Scroll down till you see plain *Arc*, just above *Arc Dark* in the following image, and select it and click *Apply*. That's it.

[image: Arc Light]

The easy, and preferred, way to edit files in `~/.local/share/color-schemes` is via the GUI provided by opening *Colors*, selecting the scheme and playing with it. To be safe, when prompted to save changes, use a new name such as Arc-1, Arc-2, etc so that the original is unmodified.

By the way, I'm going back to the original because some icons are looking different or messed up!

Note that you can modify the original *Breeze* and *Breeze Dark* themes using the *Color* GUI but remember to save under a new name!

---

**Further edit:**

There's a detailed answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/964891/248158) which points to the actual location of the downloaded theme and that is in the `desktoptheme` and `look-and-feel` folders within `~/.local/share/plasma`. This is useful if you want to remove themes installed via `Download New Look And Feel Packages`.

Comment: In which folder are those saved locally?

Comment: I edited the answer to include `/home/dkb/.local/share/color-schemes/Arc.colors`.

Comment: Thanks for the paths. Colors does a great deal of the looks. Paradoxically, openSUSE has not set any openSUSE-named *.colors files, and instead uses Breeze. I think that the *.colors files have nothing to do with the look of the terminal. I edited the inital post by adding two screenshots of the terminals. Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. What version of `konsole` do you have in OpenSuse? Mine is Version 17.12.3 in Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: In Kubuntu 18.04 I have 17.12.3 and in openSUSE Tumbleweed I have 18.08.0.

Answer (score 0):

KDE is from upstream of both Kubuntu & OpenSUSE, so at most you like the configuration of opensuse better than kubuntu, as neither design it (though depending on what versions you are comparing, it could be nothing more than you liked one version of KDE better than the other version on the other distro).

Because the configs you're talking about are KDE (which isn't unique to either) it will transfer from one to the other as long as versions of KDE are similar (or the config files work in both versions of KDE (*which in my experience is very likely*).

You'll find config etc. files are in

- ~/.config
- ~/.local

assuming we're talking Qt5/KDE5. Themes are mostly in ~/.local, but programs can decide where they store their own files, or which they use.

You can just copy these from machine to machine (regardless of distro in nearly all cases).

Comment: Is there one folder that contains all the settings to a certain theme? In openSUSE Tumbleweed under `Settings > Workspace Theme > Look and Feel` I have a clickable theme called openSUSE. But I cannot find it in `~/.config` nor in `~/.local`.

Comment: In KDE4 it was a lot easier, in KDE5 no sorry.  I booted at openSUSE Leap 15, and my chosen theme was 'Deepin Dark'; which I found in ~/.local/share/aurorae/themes/QuasiDeepinDark/  (many files, including README, metadata.desktop, however part of theme was found in ~/.local/share/color-schemes/QuasiDeepinDark.colors. That 'chosen' theme consists of 8 files in 3 locations (also in ~/.local/share/app-info/extensions-web.xml.   I would suggest adding a new KDE theme to your box, and look at where it downloads too to confirm; my default DEsktop is XFCE, not KDE)