# Themes won't uninstall from Global Themes in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, themes, uninstall, 20.04, plasma

I'm new to Linux, and KDE in particular.

**Backstory:**

I've upgraded from Kubuntu 18.04 to Kubuntu 20.04 recently, and I've encountered a weird problem when I try to install a new theme.

I install themes using the "Global Theme" menu in the settings, by clicking the "Get New Global Themes..." button. The theme I choose, is being installed correctly, but, when I press the "uninstall button", and it disappears from the "Get New Global Themes" browser, I can still see it in the menu of the Installed Global Themes, alongside with the default themes that came out-of-the-box with the system.

And of course, the files of that "deleted" theme are still present in the system, even tho, I clicked on the "uninstall" button. (reboots don't help)

I didn't have that problem when I've been using Kubuntu 18.04 and it only appeared after the upgrade. I already read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964296/plasma-shows-themes-etc-as-installed-though-they-are-not-and-vice-versa) thread, but I would like to ask again, since the answer in that thread isn't clear enough for me.

**The question:**

Is it a problem on my side? If so, what should I do to fix it, and not delete all the files manually?

If it's a KDE problem, do you know whether it was fixed in the latest KDE Plasma releases? (I.e. Plasma 5.18.5, etc.) -- I could not find any relevant information regarding this topic besides the thread I mentioned above.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was fixed in later versions of KDE.
The bug ticket is still open if I'm not mistaken, but the problem disappeared on my end.
I've moved since to OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and now I'm on Manjaro, and did not encounter that problem since.

Now I'm using Manjaro (stable), with:

1. KDE: 5.19.4
2. KDE Framework: 5.73.0
3. Qt: 5.15.0
4. Kernel: 5.7.14

Answer (score 2):

I deleted look-and-feel/ and desktoptheme/ directories from ~/.local/share/plasma
And themes disapeared!

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
Apparently, it was fixed in later versions of KDE.
I mean, the bug ticket is still open if I'm not mistaken, but the problem itself disappeared on my end.

Comment: Also, the whole point of this question is, to eliminate the need of manual deletion of directories.